# Substitution Strings Update without Page Submission

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I have a Dynamic Action **D1** with a custom attribute **C1**. **C1** is a text field that uses substitution string referring the page item **P_ITEM** as **&P_ITEM.** But the **&P_ITEM.** is only substituted during rendering of page.

I also have a dynamic action **D2** which updates the **P_ITEM** in session state. If I try to run the action **D1** which uses **&P_ITEM.**, instead of using the new value in session state, it still uses the old value during the time of page rendering. In this scenario, I can only run **D1** as expected if I submit the page. Now, the question is, how do I update **&P_ITEM.** without page submission? Is it even possible? I know that there is Page items to submit option if it were a SQL Source which uses bind variable **:P_ITEM.** BUT this is specifically using substitution string as **&P_ITEM.**

**One of the solution might be to re-render the dynamic action without rendering the page. It is just the idea I have and I don't know if this can be done or not.**

Comment: if that value is in your html page, you can check for the respective selector and then force a manual change with javascript/jquery.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you might use substitution strings (e.g. `&P_ITEM.`) is *because you don't want* them to react to session state changes on the client.

If you want the value of the state of the item on the client, use javascript `$v("P_ITEM")`, or if you're running a PL/SQL dynamic action, pass it as a bind variable `:P_ITEM`.

Comment: I am using a Plugin as a dynamic action that has custom attribute. Custom attribute allows substitution string only in the format `&P_ITEM.` I guess I don't have any other options.

Comment: Yes, it may or may not be tricky to rewrite the plugin to allow it to react dynamically to changes to the item. Depends on the plugin.